# Команда LIMIT в SQLite

Tags: sqlite, limit

Здравствуйте.
Начал недавно изучать SQLite, и в целом сложностей пока не встречал, но одна команда надо мной, буквально, издевается.
При попытке добавить LIMIT в строку:

```
myDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM users WHERE name = 'Pit'");
```

Мне выдается ошибка '(', ',', BETWEEN , IN or semicolon exected, got 'LIMIT' и команда не выполняется. В остальном все работает без проблем. Поиск по интернету ничего не принес, каких-либо специфичных условий для LIMIT я не нашел.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я думаю что нужно пересмотреть логику действий. Выход замуж за первого встречного, будь то Pit или кто еще, никого до добра не доводил - должен быть критерий, по которому из всех Pit'ов вы выберете наиболее подходящего для  удаления, ну к примеру если он Brad Pitt ;-))

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [документации](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html) SQLite не поддерживает конструкцию `DELETE ... LIMIT`

Comment: Согласно документации, таки может поддерживать, если скомпилирован с соответствующей опцией. :)